# Unable to convert a sparse matrix to a dense one

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have the matrices `Gx` and `Gy` both sparse of type coo.

I perform the following operations with them:

```
A = np.hstack((Gx.transpose(),Gy.transpose()))
B = np.vstack((Gx,Gy))

L = np.dot(A,B)
```

I want to visualize the solution, C so I have used C.toarray() and C.todense(), but the answer is the following:

```
In [391]: C
Out[391]: 
  array([ <16x16 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 64 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)


In [392]: C.toarray() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<ipython-input-390-86c90f8dce51>", line 1, in <module>
    C.toarray()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toarray'
```

How could I do to see the matrix `C` in a dense form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From:

```
array([ <16x16 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
```

with 64 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)

I deduce that `C` is a 1 element dense array with `dtype=object`.  That one element is a sparse matrix.

So I expect that

```
 C[0].toarray()
```

will work. As the error says, a `numpy` array does not have a `toarray` method.  But in this case its element does.

Since `Gx` and `Gy` are sparse, then you need to use the sparse versions of `hstack` and `vstack`, not the `numpy` versions.  Check the type of `A` and `B`.  I be those are numpy arrays, not sparse matrices.

---

Look what happens when I use `np.hstack` with a couple of sparse matrices:

```
In [70]: M=sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1,2],[2,3,4]])
In [71]: np.hstack([M,M])
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:298: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using >= and <= is inefficient, using <, >, or !=, instead.
  "using <, >, or !=, instead.", SparseEfficiencyWarning)
Out[71]: 
array([ <2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

The result is not sparse, rather it dense with 2 sparse elements.